# How to fix AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: false == true?

Tags: angular

I'am using an relative old angular version app:

```
Angular CLI: 1.7.4
Node: 8.11.1
OS: darwin x64
Angular: 5.2.10
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, language-service, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router

@angular/cdk: 5.2.5
@angular/cli: 1.7.4
@angular/material-moment-adapter: 6.4.2
@angular/material: 5.2.5
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer: 0.3.2
@angular-devkit/core: 0.3.2
@angular-devkit/schematics: 0.3.2
@ngtools/json-schema: 1.2.0
@ngtools/webpack: 1.10.2
@schematics/angular: 0.3.2
@schematics/package-update: 0.3.2
typescript: 2.4.2
webpack: 3.11.0
```

The app runs fine and but time to time it just quit and throws the following error on the console:

> AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: false == true
>       at PriorityNode.removeChild (/Users/xxxx/yyyy/node_modules/spdy-transport/lib/spdy-transport/priority.js:74:3)
>       at PriorityNode.remove (/Users/xxxx/yyyy/node_modules/spdy-transport/lib/spdy-transport/priority.js:62:15)
>       at PriorityTree.add (/Users/xxxx/yyyy/node_modules/spdy-transport/lib/spdy-transport/priority.js:163:23)
>       at Stream._initPriority (/Users/xxxx/yyyy/node_modules/spdy-transport/lib/spdy-transport/stream.js:101:25)
>       at new Stream (/Users/xxxx/yyyy/node_modules/spdy-transport/lib/spdy-transport/stream.js:76:8)
>       at Connection._createStream (/Users/xxxx/yyyy/node_modules/spdy-transport/lib/spdy-transport/connection.js:388:16)
>       at Connection._handleHeaders (/Users/xxxx/yyyy/node_modules/spdy-transport/lib/spdy-transport/connection.js:436:21)
>       at Connection._handleFrame (/Users/xxxx/yyyy/node_modules/spdy-transport/lib/spdy-transport/connection.js:319:10)
>       at Parser. (/Users/xxxx/yyyy/node_modules/spdy-transport/lib/spdy-transport/connection.js:156:10)
>       at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
>       at Parser.emit (events.js:211:7)
>       at addChunk (/Users/xxxx/yyyy/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js:284:12)
>       at readableAddChunk (/Users/xxxx/yyyy/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js:271:11)
>       at Parser.Readable.push (/Users/xxxx/yyyy/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js:238:10)
>       at Parser.Transform.push (/Users/xxxx/yyyy/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_transform.js:146:32)
>       at next (/Users/xxxx/yyyy/node_modules/spdy-transport/lib/spdy-transport/protocol/base/parser.js:53:12)

Have been searching and found [this one](https://github.com/spdy-http2/spdy-transport/pull/57), but it looks a kind of different to my issue and none of the suggestions could give me the right fix.

Any hint or idea how to fix this? I notice this error after I did implement an eventEmitter function to pass some data from child to parent component.
Could this be the reason?